# Click handler for dynamic inserted content from axios

Tags: vuejs2

Im using displayLog function in my vue methods to render logs (in foreach loop) I got from axios.
And i need to bind some handler to my dynamic content, for example changeThisNote.
How can i bind it to my dynamic inserted content?
If I code '@click="changeThisNote' Vue doesn't render it as I need.
Thanks.

```js
methods: {
  displayLog: function(log) {
    let str = '';
    let space = ' ';
    let date = log.created_at;...str = '<div class="note" @click="changeThisNote(' + log.id + ')"><div class="note__date">' 
      + date + space + name 
      + '</div><div class="note__body" id="note_' + log.id + '">' + log.msg + '</div><div></div></div>';
    return str;
  },
  changeThisNote: function(log_id) {
    // here I need hide note__body, insert textarea with its data for editing
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be building strings of HTML and inserting them into the DOM. That's missing out on some of the best features of Vue.

What you should do instead is use data to drive your template.

For example, store an array of *log* data in your component and render that in your template. When your Axios request completes, the template will update automatically

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({ logs: [] }),
  methods: {
    async getLogs () {
      const { data } = await axios.get("/logs") // just an example
      this.logs = data.map(log => ({
        ...log,
        editing: false // add an "editing" flag
      }))
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div 
  v-for="log in logs"
  :key="log.id"
  class="note"
  @click="log.editing = true"
>
  <div class="note__date">
    {{ log.created_at }}
    {{ log.name }} <!--  not sure where "name" was meant to come from -->
  </div>
  <textarea v-if="log.editing" v-model="log.msg"></textarea>
  <div v-else class="note__body" :id="`note_${log.id}">
    {{ log.msg }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Phil! I'll try. What do the ':key="log.id"' means?

Comment: When I click on my div note__body hides and textarea is shown. But when I click on it to focus on textarea its hides and note__body shown again. And I want to be able do changes in textarea.

Comment: I've updated my answer to just switch editing _on_ when you click (instead of toggling) but really, you should be figuring out what state to set and when

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way would be to create the html element like this:

```js
// ...
methods: {
  displayLog (log) {
    
   const div = document.createElement('div')
   div.classList.add('note')
   div.addEventListener('click', this.changeThisNote(log.id))
   div.innerHTML = '<div class="note__date">' + date + space + name + '</div><div class="note__body" id="note_'+log.id+'">' + log.msg + '</div><div></div>'
  }
}
// ...
```

Comment: `this.changeThisNote(log.id)` will execute the method immediately

Comment: Thanks, Babacar Cissé Dia! I will try your code and answer you later ;)

Comment: @Phil it will only if the click handler is called don't you think ?